# Iterator.continually: special proccessing for the first element

Tags: multithreading, scala, iterator, synchronized

I have an `Iterator` based on a repeatedly function calls:

```
anObject.synchronized {
    Iterator.continually { 
        anObject.wait()      // skip this call for the 1st iteration
        Try(anObject.foo()) 
    }.dropWhile(_.isFailure).next()
    anObject.notifyAll()
}
```

I would like to make first iteration without calling `anObject.wait()`. Certainly, I could make something like the following:

```
anObject.synchronized {
    if (Try(anObject.foo()).isFailure) {
        Iterator.continually { 
            anObject.wait()
            Try(anObject.foo()) 
        }.dropWhile(_.isFailure).next()
    }
    anObject.notifyAll()
}
```

Is there more elegant or standard approach to obtain same purpose (skip function call on first iteration)

**PS** Similar task arises when it is needed to print a list with delimiters:

```
scala> List("a", "b", "c").mkString(", ")
res1: String = a, b, c
```

So, I hope there is some approach for my question too

Comment: I can't add an answer right now but what about `Iterator.single(f) ++ Iterator.continually(g)`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez - Thank you. I guess, it's interesting solution. I would like to upvote the answer :)

Comment: I just realized that won't work because `single` is eager, which is not probably what you want. BTW, since you have concurrency and multi-threading here, let me tell you an **Iterator** will be problematic. I would suggest you to switch to a robust streaming solution like **AkkaStreams**, **fs2**, **monix observables** or **Zio ZStreams**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez - Thank you. Then this question [interests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61809700/scala-iterator-for-multithreading) me too

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps create a new iterator which check for the first element

```
def continually[A](firstElem: => A)(elem: => A): Iterator[A] = new AbstractIterator[A] {
    var isFirst = true
    def hasNext = true
    def next(): A = if (isFirst) { isFirst = false; firstElem } else elem
  }

continually("a")("b").take(3).foreach(print)
// abb
```

Answer (score 2):

You could change `.continually` to `.tabulate` as long as 2,147,483,647 wouldn't be a meaningful limitation on the number of iterations.

```
anObject.synchronized {
    Iterator.tabulate { n => 
        if (n != 0) anObject.wait()  // skip 1st iteration
        Try(anObject.foo()) 
    }.dropWhile(_.isFailure).next()
    anObject.notifyAll()
}
```