# Scala Iterator for multithreading

Tags: multithreading, scala, iterator, thread-safety, synchronized

I am using scala `Iterator` for waiting loop in `synchronized` block:

```scala
anObject.synchronized {
    if (Try(anObject.foo()).isFailure) {
        Iterator.continually { 
            anObject.wait()
            Try(anObject.foo()) 
        }.dropWhile(_.isFailure).next()
    }
    anObject.notifyAll()
}
```

Is it acceptable to use `Iterator` with concurrency and multithreading? If not, why? And then what to use and how?

---

There are some details, if it matters. `anObject` is a mutable queue. And there are multiple producers and consumers to the queue. So the block above is a code of such producer or consumer. `anObject.foo` is a common simplified declaration of function that either enqueue (for producer) or dequeue (for consumer) data to/from the queue.

Answer (score 2):

`Iterator` is mutable internally, so you have to take that into consideration if you use it in multi-threaded environment. If you guaranteed that you won't end up in situation when e.g.

- 2 threads check `hasNext()`
- one of them calls `next()` - it happens to be the last element
- the other calls `next()` - NPE

(or similar) then you should be ok. In your example `Iterator` doesn't even leave the scope, so the errors shouldn't come from `Iterator`.

However, in your code I see the issue with having `aObject.wait()` and `aObject.notifyAll()` next to each other - if you call `.wait` then you won't reach `.notifyAll` which would unblock it. You can check in REPL that this hangs:

```
@ val anObject = new Object { def foo() = throw new Exception }
anObject: {def foo(): Nothing} = ammonite.$sess.cmd21$$anon$1@126ae0ca

@ anObject.synchronized {
      if (Try(anObject.foo()).isFailure) {
          Iterator.continually {
              anObject.wait()
              Try(anObject.foo())
          }.dropWhile(_.isFailure).next()
      }
      anObject.notifyAll()
  }
// wait indefinitelly
```

I would suggest changing the design to NOT rely on `wait` and `notifyAll`. However, from your code it is hard to say what you want to achieve so I cannot tell if this is more like `Promise`-`Future` case, `monix.Observable`, `monix.Task` or something else.

---

If your use case is a queue, produces and consumers, then it sound like a use case for reactive streams - e.g. FS2 + Monix, but it could be FS2+IO or something from Akka Streams

```
val queue: Queue[Task, Item] // depending on use case queue might need to be bounded

// in one part of the application
queue.enqueu1(item) // Task[Unit]

// in other part of the application
queue
  .dequeue
  .evalMap { item =>
    // ...
    result: Task[Result]
  }
  .compile
  .drain
```

This approach would require some change in thinking about designing an application, because you would no longer work on thread directly, but rather designed a flow data and declaring what is sequential and what can be done in parallel, where threads become just an implementation detail.

Comment: Thank you (+1). I've provide the question with some details.